# Trying to create a script based in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a script to generate a insert for another table. This is what I'm using:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @sql = 'select update  UNIDADE set values(CDUNIDADE=' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CD_UNIDADE)  
+ ', CDINSTITUICAO=' + 'Ajustar' + ', NOUNIDADE=' 
+ '''' + NO_UNIDADE+ ''''  + ', NORESUMO=' + '''' + NO_UNIDADE+ ''''  + '
, CNPJ=' + '''' + NO_CNPJ + '''' + ', ENDERECO=' + '''' + NO_ENDERECO + '''' + ', BAIRRO=' + '''' + NO_BAIRRO + '''' + ',
 CEP=' + '''' + NO_CEP + '''' + '
, CDCIDADE=' + CD_CIDADE +', FONE1=' + '''' + NO_TELEFONEDIRETOR + '''' + ', FONE2=' + '''' + NO_TELEFONECOORDENADOR + '''' + 
', DIRETOR=' + '''' + NO_DIRETOR + '''' + ', EMAIL_DIRETOR=' + '''' + NO_EMAILDIRETOR + '''' + 
', VDE=' + NULL + ', EMAIL_VDE=' + NULL + ', COORDENADOR=' + '''' + NO_COORDENADOR + '''' + ', EMAIL_COORD=' + '''' + NO_EMAILCOORDENADOR + '''' + '
, SENHA=' + '''' + NO_SENHA + '''' +', CDTIPOUNIDADE=' + NULL +'
, CDUNIDADE_ANT=' + NULL +', CDINSTITUICAO_ANT=' + NULL +', NOCONTRATANTE=' + NULL +', CNPJ_CONTRATANTE=' + NULL +'
, SENHA_ANTERIOR=' + NULL +', OBSERVACAO=' + NULL +  ') where CDUNIDADE = '+ CD_UNIDADE  from UNIDADE
```

When I try to execute this statement, I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', FONE1=' to data type int.

In this camp i have this try type of data:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
(xx)xxxx-xxxx
NULL
```

And the camp is a `nvarchar` with 32 length.

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT

I changed my code to this. Now it almost work, it create a script for every row in the table but all is null.

```
select 'update  UNIDADE set (CDUNIDADE=' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CD_UNIDADE)  
+ ', CDINSTITUICAO=' + 'Ajustar' + ', NOUNIDADE=' 
+ '''' + NO_UNIDADE+ ''''  + ', NORESUMO=' + '''' + NO_UNIDADE+ ''''  + '
, CNPJ=' + '''' + NO_CNPJ + '''' + ', ENDERECO=' + '''' + NO_ENDERECO + '''' + ', BAIRRO=' + '''' + NO_BAIRRO + '''' + ',
 CEP=' + '''' + NO_CEP + '''' + '
, CDCIDADE=' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CD_CIDADE) +', FONE1=' + '''' + NO_TELEFONEDIRETOR + '''' + ', FONE2=' + '''' + NO_TELEFONECOORDENADOR + '''' + 
', DIRETOR=' + '''' + NO_DIRETOR + '''' + ', EMAIL_DIRETOR=' + '''' + NO_EMAILDIRETOR + '''' + 
', VDE=' + NULL + ', EMAIL_VDE=' + NULL + ', COORDENADOR=' + '''' + NO_COORDENADOR + '''' + ', EMAIL_COORD=' + '''' + NO_EMAILCOORDENADOR + '''' + '
, SENHA=' + '''' + NO_SENHA + '''' +', CDTIPOUNIDADE=' + NULL +'
, CDUNIDADE_ANT=' + NULL +', CDINSTITUICAO_ANT=' + NULL +', NOCONTRATANTE=' + NULL +', CNPJ_CONTRATANTE=' + NULL +'
, SENHA_ANTERIOR=' + NULL +', OBSERVACAO=' + NULL +  ') where CDUNIDADE = '+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CD_UNIDADE)    from UNIDADE
```

Comment: it's conversion issue just use CAST(FONE1 AS VARCHAR(10)) = Instead of ', FONE1='

Comment: Do a PRINT(@sql) and review your code, will be easy to spot the mistake. As a side note, why don't you avoid dynamic SQL for this update? Doesn't seem necesary and it's way prone to errors.

Comment: This makes no sense.. you are updating a table with values from the same table? Is that intentional? you have a ton of syntax issues BTW and this string will be NULL once you fix all of those. Dynamic SQL is not needed here

Comment: Cast didnt work, print didnt work also. I'm updating tables from diferent servers, that table uses the same name.

Comment: Have you tried to `PRINT @sql` before executing it???

Comment: i'm not using @sql anymore. i Edit my question, this is is almost working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for dynamic SQL here. It seems like you are trying to update a table with values from a single row... or set them to string literals. Here is how that would be accomplished:

```
update  UNIDADE  
set 
    CDUNIDADE = 'cd_unidade'
    ,CDINSTITUICAO = 'Ajustar' 
    ,NOUNIDADE = 'no_unidade' 
    ,NORESUMO = 'no_unidade'
    ,CNPJ = 'no_cnpj'
    ,ENDERECO = 'no_endereco' 
    ,BAIRRO= 'no_bairro' 
    ,CEP= 'no_cep' 
    ,CDCIDADE = 'cd_cidade 
    ,FONE1 = 'no_telefonediretor 
    ,FONE2 = 'no_telefonecoordenador'
    ,DIRETOR = 'no_diretor'
    ,EMAIL_DIRETOR = 'no_emaildiretor'
    ,VDE = NULL
    ,EMAIL_VDE = NULL
    ,COORDENADOR = 'no_coordenador' 
    ,EMAIL_COORD = 'no_emailcoordenador'
    ,SENHA = 'no_senha'
    ,CDTIPOUNIDADE = NULL
    ,CDUNIDADE_ANT = NULL 
    ,CDINSTITUICAO_ANT = NULL 
    ,NOCONTRATANTE = NULL 
    ,CNPJ_CONTRATANTE = NULL 
    ,SENHA_ANTERIOR = NULL 
    ,OBSERVACAO = NULL
where CDUNIDADE = 'CD_UNIDADE'
```

If you have a typo and you meant to list different table names, then you need to update with a join. Something like this:

```
update u  
set 
    CDUNIDADE = o.cd_unidade
    ,CDINSTITUICAO = o.Ajustar 
    ,NOUNIDADE = o.no_unidade 
    ,NORESUMO = o.no_unidade
    ,CNPJ = o.no_cnpj
    ,ENDERECO = o.no_endereco 
    ,BAIRRO= o.no_bairro 
    ,CEP= o.no_cep 
    ,CDCIDADE = o.cd_cidade 
    ,FONE1 = o.no_telefonediretor 
    ,FONE2 = o.no_telefonecoordenador
    ,DIRETOR = o.no_diretor
    ,EMAIL_DIRETOR = o.no_emaildiretor
    ,VDE = NULL
    ,EMAIL_VDE = NULL
    ,COORDENADOR = o.no_coordenador 
    ,EMAIL_COORD = o.no_emailcoordenador
    ,SENHA = o.no_senha
    ,CDTIPOUNIDADE = NULL
    ,CDUNIDADE_ANT = NULL 
    ,CDINSTITUICAO_ANT = NULL 
    ,NOCONTRATANTE = NULL 
    ,CNPJ_CONTRATANTE = NULL 
    ,SENHA_ANTERIOR = NULL 
    ,OBSERVACAO = NULL
from UNIDADE u
inner join someOtherTable o on o.id = u.id
```

Comment: i'm trying to update table from diferent servers, that's why i need to generetate a script to run in the other server.

Comment: For that, you'd use a [**linked server**](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/). Dynamic SQL does nothing here to help pull data from another server. It would fail since you haven't fully qualified it, and aren't using `OPENQUERY` or a `LINKED SERVER`

Answer (score 0):

I make it work. I used this code.

```
select  'update  UNIDADE set  CDUNIDADE=' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CD_UNIDADE) + ', NOUNIDADE=' 
 + '''' + NO_UNIDADE + ''''  +', NORESUMO=' + '''' + NO_UNIDADE+ ''''  + '
, CNPJ=' + '''' + ISNULL(NO_CNPJ,'NULL') + '''' + ', ENDERECO=' + '''' +  ISNULL(NO_ENDERECO,'NULL') + '''' 
+ ', BAIRRO=' + '''' +ISNULL(NO_BAIRRO,'NULL' )  + '''' + ' ,
 CEP=' + '''' + ISNULL(NO_CEP,'NULL') + '''' + ', CDCIDADE=' +   ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CD_CIDADE),'NULL') +'
 , FONE1=' + '''' + ISNULL(NO_TELEFONEDIRETOR,'NULL' )  + '''' + ', FONE2=' + '''' +  ISNULL(NO_TELEFONECOORDENADOR,'NULL' ) + '''' + 
', DIRETOR=' + '''' + ISNULL(NO_DIRETOR,'NULL' ) + '''' + ', EMAIL_DIRETOR=' + '''' + ISNULL(NO_EMAILDIRETOR,'NULL' ) + '''' + 
', COORDENADOR=' + '''' +ISNULL(NO_COORDENADOR,'NULL' )  + '''' + ', EMAIL_COORD=' + '''' +ISNULL(NO_EMAILCOORDENADOR,'NULL' )   + '''' + '
, SENHA=' + '''' + NO_SENHA + '''' +'  
 where CDUNIDADE ='+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CD_UNIDADE)   from UNIDADE
```